# Enter function from .click on link

Tags: jquery, html

I am obtaining values from a text input field.

jQuery:

```
$('.submitLocation').click(function(){

    // get value from input field
    var city = $(".city").val();
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="city" class="city" placeholder="City Name">
<button class="submitLocation">Set location</button></br>
```

I want the same thing to happen when a user clicks on a list item comprised of historic searches. I am able to list the results, but unable to get the function to fire again when a list item is selected.

I have tried to address this by assigning the city class to the list items and then creating a function that fires the initial function.

```
var weather = [];
var weatherLength;
var text;
var i;

function showCurrent(currentWeather) {
console.log(currentWeather);
console.log(currentWeather.name);

weather.push( currentWeather.name );

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

    // Store
    // saves name/s in local storage (for histoy list)
    localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify( weather ) );

    // saves name in session storage for current use
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);

    // Retrieve
    // Retrieves name from session storage 
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

    weatherLength = weather.length;
    text = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i < weatherLength; i++) {
        text += "<li class='city'>" + "<a href='location.html' class='submitExistingLocation'>" + weather[i] + "</a>" + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("record2").innerHTML = text;

    $('.submitExistingLocation').click(function(){
        $('.submitLocation').click(); // Trigger search button click event
    })
```

html

```
<div id="record2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating multiple list items that have CSS class `city` on them:

> ```
> text = "<ul>";
> for (i = 0; i < weatherLength; i++) {
>     text += "<li class='city'>" + "<a href='location.html' class='submitExistingLocation'>" + weather[i] + "</a>" + "</li>";
> }
> text += "</ul>";
> ```

Then, in your click event handler, you are getting the value using `$(".city").val();`. According to [documentation of `.val()` function](https://api.jquery.com/val/) in jQuery:

> [It gets] the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements...

Notice that in your case the first element is not necessarily the element that's been clicked.

To correct the selector, you can use `event.target` property to get the element that has been clicked, and store it in a global variable so that it is available in the click handler for `.submitLocation`.

---

Another problem is the `city` class is being set on an `<li>` element, which doesn't have a value attribute. So `.val()` would return `undefined`. In order to get the text inside the list item, you should be calling `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Here's how your code might look like in the end:

```
var clickedElement = undefined;
...

$('.submitLocation').click(function(){
    if(clickedElement !== undefined) {
        // Get the TEXT from clicked list item.
        var city = $(clickedElement).text();

        // Clear the value of clicked element.
        clickedElement = undefined;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}     

...
$('.submitExistingLocation').click(function(event){
    // Keep track of the element that was clicked.
    clickedElement = event.target;

    //Trigger search button click event
    $('.submitLocation').click();
});
```

Comment: Note the code is untested so far, but I have attempted to point out the problems in the code. If this still doesn't work, please create a [mcve] and edit it into the question itself.